# Getting started with Shopify, local development on Windows

Tags: themes, hosting, localhost, shopify

I'm looking to start building e-commerce sites with Shopify.

I was just wondering if anyone has experience of doing so on Windows (shopify's support page mainly seems to be Mac OS orientated).

Most importantly I was wondering how people work on themes on a local environment with shopify.

Any advice on how I should best set up a building environment for Shopify would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on windows, have a look at this gem - https://rubygems.org/gems/shopify_theme